# Adding points to geom_hline

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a timeseries with a geom_hline using the FL_Actions and the point data for that line. So far, I've been able to add the geom_hline but I am having problems adding the geom_point with the labels for FL_Action where 1 is equal to closing down policies and 2 is equal to opening up policies. I am using this dataset (see sample below):

```
# A tibble: 22 x 10
   Date    Date2   Date3   FLORIDA FLday MICHIGAN MIday FL_Actions MI_Actions realdate  
   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <date>    
 1 3/6/20  3/6/20  3/6/20        3     0        0     0         NA         NA 2020-03-06
 2 3/7/20  3/7/20  3/7/20        7     4        0     0         NA         NA 2020-03-07
 3 3/8/20  3/8/20  3/8/20       10     3        0     0         NA         NA 2020-03-08
 4 3/9/20  3/9/20  3/9/20       13     3        0     0          1         NA 2020-03-09
 5 3/10/20 3/10/20 3/10/20      15     2        0     0         NA          1 2020-03-10
 6 3/11/20 3/11/20 3/11/20      24     9        2     2          1         NA 2020-03-11
 7 3/12/20 3/12/20 3/12/20      30     6        3     1         NA         NA 2020-03-12
 8 3/13/20 3/13/20 3/13/20      45    15       22    19         NA         NA 2020-03-13
 9 3/14/20 3/14/20 3/14/20      64    19       35    13         NA         NA 2020-03-14
10 3/15/20 3/15/20 3/15/20     100    36       45    10         NA         NA 2020-03-15
# … with 12 more rows
```

This is my current code:

```
ggplot(MI_FL_Data, aes(realdate, FLday))+
geom_line() + 
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 15000), data=MI_FL_Data, linetype=2) +
geom_hline(aes(yintercept=17000), data=MI_FL_Data, linetype=4) + 
geom_point(aes(col=8, 15000)) + 
geom_point(aes(col=8,17000)) + 
labs(x=NULL, y="Number of Reported Daily COVID Cases", title="State of Florida") + 
theme_classic()
```

However, I keep getting an error which says: *Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only.*

I think I need to add the realdate (I used `library(lubridate)` to create the realdate variable), but want only dates that are coded 1 to go on one geom_hline and those coded 2 to go on the other geom_hline. Would this look something like:

```
geom_point(aes(realdate, col=8 if.1) yintercept 17000)
```

or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

The line `geom_point(aes(col=8, 15000))` generates an error. I am not sure what is that supposed to do. Also I don't get why your `yintercept` is as high as 15000,17000 when the values on y-axis are in the range 0-36 (atleast for the data shown).

This works but I don't know if you had this in mind.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(MI_FL_Data, aes(realdate, FLday))+
  geom_line() + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 15), linetype=2) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=17), linetype=4) + 
  labs(x=NULL, y="Number of Reported Daily COVID Cases", 
       title="State of Florida") + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: The daily cases in Florida range from 0-16,000. The snippet only has 36 rows of data from the early days of the pandemic.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to post an image, but if you follow this link, you'll see the current iteration: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17aDicp2Ul2jOM-PvvkpSnlVME5cjUgpH/view?usp=sharing. What I am trying to do is get the 1 and 2 labels above the time series on the geom_hlines.

Answer (score -1):

It appears your date columns are actually formatted as characters. Can you change them to date and see if that helps? You can `mutate` them and write over them with `as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%y"). As for the second point, you could supply the data argument and filter inside the individual calls, for example.

Comment: I have a variable called realdate that I can use which was created using `lubridate`, but I'm not sure what you mean by supply the data argument and filter inside the individual calls? Do you mean something for the geom_point line? It (realdate) is already in that line of code.

Comment: Sorry I might have misread which column you were using initially. But yes for the geom_point line, for example `geom_hline(data = MI_FL_data %>% filter(FL_actions == 2), aes(yintercept = 15000), linetype=2)`.

Comment: This is my code:
```ggplot(MI_FL_Data, aes(realdate, FLday))+    geom_line() +    geom_hline(data = MI_FL_Data %>% filter(FL_Actions == 1), aes(yintercept = 15000), linetype=2)+ geom_hline(data = MI_FL_Data %>% filter(FL_Actions == 2), aes(yintercept = 17000), linetype=2) +  geom_point(aes(realdate, 15000)) +  geom_point(aes(realdate,17000)) + geom_text(aes(label=FL_Actions), check_overlap=TRUE)+geom_label(data=MI_FL_Data, aes(label=FL_Actions), nudge_x = 0.50, nudge_y=.25, size=2)+labs(x=NULL, y="Number of Reported Daily COVID Cases", title="State of Florida")+ theme_classic()```